# largest element of heap in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code that uses a heap to get the dictionary elements with the highest value, but it's not returning the expected result:

```
import heapq
import operator
a={'third': 3, 'fourth': 2, 'first': 5, 'second': 4}
heapq.nlargest(4,a,operator.itemgetter(1))
>>['fourth', 'first', 'third', 'second']
```

Why is it not returning:

```
>>['first' , 'second' , 'third' , 'fourth']
```

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at what `operator.itemgetter(1)` actually does to your dictionary:

```
>>> map(operator.itemgetter(1), a)
['e', 'o', 'h', 'i']
```

When you iterate over a dictionary, you iterate over the keys. Since you want the *values*, use use `a.get` to fetch the items:

```
>>> map(a.get, a)
[4, 2, 3, 5]
```

`a.get(key)` is a method that works like `a[key]`, so it's essentially doing this:

```
>>> [a[key] for key in a]
[4, 2, 3, 5]
```

And now your code works:

```
>>> heapq.nlargest(4, a, a.get)
['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
```

Comment: +1. But why iterate the keys and use `a.get` instead of just iterating the items? (I'm not complaining about efficiency here—`get` is O(1), and who cares anyway with just 4 items. I just think it's easier to understand, and closer to what the OP expected, to deal with the items.)

Comment: @abarnert: You know what, I have no idea. I remember doing it this way a while ago and it worked.

Comment: Wow, very clever! No messing around with .items()

Comment: @Blender: Of course it works just fine either way. It's just a matter of which is simpler to understand. You don't want the OP to just use some code because it looks like it does the right thing, without knowing what it actually does, right?

Comment: Actually, I think iterating over the keys is simpler to understand than iterating over the items as you suggested. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @sazpaz: Aren't you iterating over both the keys and values?

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over a `dict`, you're iterating over its keys.

So, when you apply `operator.itemgetter(1)`, you're getting `key[1]` for each key. Which means the second letter of each name.

If you want to iterate over the keys and values, use `items`:

```
>>> heapq.nlargest(4,a.items(),operator.itemgetter(1))
[('first', 5), ('second', 4), ('third', 3), ('fourth', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`operator.itemgetter(1)` doesn't do what you think it does. Try this:

```
>>> heapq.nlargest(4, a, a.__getitem__)
['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
```

`operator.itemgetter(1)` would just fetch the element with key `1` from everything passed to it, which, in this case, is the second letter of each word. And indeed, `'o' > 'i' >= 'i' > 'e'`.

Comment: Well, `operator.itemgetter(1)` _does_ do what the OP thinks it does… it's iterating over a `dict` that doesn't do what he thinks it does.